# Whoops! Lost connection to http://198.x.x.x:hostnumber/websocket

Tags: websocket, stomp, sockjs

I am using SocksJs and getting every time **Whoops! Lost connection to Http** or if I changed the link to ws://198.x.x.x:hostnumber/websocket then i will get

**'SyntaxError: The URL's scheme must be either 'http:' or 'https:'. 'ws:' is not allowed.
SyntaxError: The URL's scheme must be either 'http:' or 'https:'. 'ws:' is not allowed.'**

also, I am sharing my code

```
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
 connectNew() {
        const socket = new SockJS(this.serverUrl);
        this.stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        this.stompClient.connect('', '', () => {
                console.log('success');
        });
    }
```

Please help if anybody knows the answer I want to run this code on my mobile phone